# Magnetism simulation

Tags: electromagnetism, simulations

I am not a physicist but I'd like to write a simulation of interactions of multiple free-falling (no gravity) magnets. I am going to visualize how magnets starts to attract or repel each other and how its attitude and angular momentum is affected due to presence of other magnets. Is there any generic formula that could be applied in such simulation? If no, could I bind at some distance two point-like particles where one is like electron and second like a positron and use n-Body simulation with electrical charge equations to simulate magnets? Would that be equivalent approach?

Comment: The magnetic field interaction of [any pair of dipoles is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Magnetic_dipole%E2%80%93dipole_interaction), though I'm not sure how "generic" or "easy" that would be to implement in a dynamic model you are hoping for. This might end up being a far more complicated task than you are hoping for.

Comment: Great article. Thank you @KyleKanos!